# Asymptotic Notation Comparison

Tags: algorithm

Is O(logn) = O(2^O(log logn))?

I tried to take the log of both sides
log logn =  log2^(log logn)
log logn = log logn log2

We can find a constant C > log2 s.t C log logn > log logn log2

So they are equal to each other. Am I right?

Comment: Whereas it's true that `log2(n) == 2^log(log(n))`, you can't really say that `O(log n) = O(2^log(log(n))`. The two notations imply different assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to ask is if `log n = O(2^(log log n))`?

Think of `O` (big-O) as a `<=` operator, but the comparison is made asymptotically.

Now, to answer your question, we have to compare `log n` and `2^(log log n)`.

We use asymptotic notations only when we need to visualize how much an algorithm will scale as the input grows drastically.

`log n` is a logarithmic function.

`2^(log log n)` is an exponential function. (Notice that `log log n` is the exponent of `2`)

It will always be true that a logarithmic function is asymptotically less than an exponential function. If you want to understand, try computing both the functions for very large values of n (like 10000 or 100000000).

So, it can be very easily inferred that `log n = O(2^(log log n))`.

NOTE: We do not compare asymptotic notations like you asked (`O(logn) = O(2^O(log logn))`). We compare functions (like `log n`) using these notations.